# OutOfMemoryException by TaskScheduler in highly concurrent async asp.net core application

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, .net-core, async-await

In an dotnet core 2.2 REST service, hosted on AWS ECS FARGATE (docker), I regularly (every 30-60 minutes) have an instance crashing with `System.OutOfMemoryException` even though ECS reports max memory usage of 11% (out of 16GB). The crash always comes from a TaskScheduler (stack trace below). It only happens in production.

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot this issue. (Edit: I don't believe this is actually an OutOfMemory issue, unless `Thread:StartInternal()` can suddenly use 90% of 16GB quicker than the AWS monitoring tools can register it)

The application works locally, on Windows 10, and I've also tried to reproduce on a separate ECS cluster (our test cluster) by sustaining 100 concurrent requests, but without luck.
One endpoint of the service receives 99%+ of requests. The basic operation is:

- Try to find some documents in a MongoDB database (based on input) using `async/await`
- Fetch data from WCF (sync, see below)
- For some of the results, fetch data from an external URL (sometimes slow) using `System.New.WebRequest` using `async/await`
- Return results

The WCF service is called sync, because we are using a client library on top of WCF, which is not async safe. However, the result is stored in a `MemoryCache` for 1 minute, and re-fetching on expiry is protected using [AsyncEx.AsyncMonitor](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncMonitor), so only one caller is allowed to update the cache, like this:

```cs
using( await _monitor.EnterAsync( ) )
{
    if( !Cache.TryGetValue( "UserLookup", out LookupUsers lookupUsers ) )
    {
        lookupUsers = await GetCachedUsers( ssoToken );
        Cache.Set( "UserLookup", lookupUsers, TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 ) );
    }
    return lookupUsers;
}
```

`GetCachedUsers()` does this:

```cs
var users = await Task.Run( ( ) => client.Proxy.ListUsers( new ListUsersInput { } ) );
```

And also returns a default in case of timeout or other problem.

The entry point of the action is this:

```cs
[Route( "get-content" )]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<RemoteGetContentResult> GetContent( [FromBody]RemoteGetContentInput input )
{
    // input validation
    var c = Interlocked.Increment( ref _concurrency );
    try
    {
        // log value of _concurrency
        return await _provider.GetContentExAsync( input );
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement( ref _concurrency );
    }
}
```

The concurrency level logged is usually 10-30, but can reach 100 (when there are many external http fetches).

Here is the stack trace I see in the AWS ECS logs:

```
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z Unhandled Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskSchedulerException: An exception was thrown by a TaskScheduler. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ScheduleAndStart(Boolean needsProtection)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ScheduleAndStart(Boolean needsProtection)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalStartNew(Task creatingTask, Delegate action, Object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskScheduler scheduler, TaskCreationOptions options, InternalTaskOptions internalOptions)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduleCallbackHelper(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduleCallbackNoFlow(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.YieldAwaitable.YieldAwaiter.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IStateMachineBoxAwareAwaiter.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(IAsyncStateMachineBox box)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted[TAwaiter,TStateMachine](TAwaiter& awaiter, TStateMachine& stateMachine)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-07-10T06:22:39.554Z    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

UPDATE:
I added some additional logging every 5 secs, about the process. At 18:30:16.741Z it logged:

```
2019-07-10T18:30:16.741Z concurrency:   4 proc thread cnt:   29 avail worker threads: 32,766 avail compl port threads:  1,000 ws: 1,733,996,544 peak ws:      0
```

So a WorkingSet of ~1.7GB out of 16GB. (For some reason Peak WS is always 0, but the max I've seen is 2,053,316,608 bytes).
4 seconds later, it throws the OOM exception:

```
2019-07-10T18:30:20.630Z Unhandled Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskSchedulerException: An exception was thrown by a TaskScheduler. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Comment: Is there any correlation between the concurrency level and the OOM exception?

Comment: @StephenCleary Not a clear correlation no, but I cannot say for sure. For instance the last one that crashed, did so with a concurrency level of ~25, but I've seen  it handle around 100 without issues

Comment: I'm adding code to log (every 5 seconds) general concurrency level (using a middleware), working set, peak working set, thread count and thread pool available counts. Any other suggestions?

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://blog.markvincze.com/troubleshooting-high-memory-usage-with-asp-net-core-on-kubernetes/)

Comment: This [might also be fixed in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/using-net-and-docker-together-dockercon-2019-update/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll try it out on 3.0 when it is released.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same growth in memory as Mark Vincze. Actually I introduced an artificial memory leak in the app, to see if the runtime somehow thought it was limited to 2GB. Even with 3GB+ leaked (allocating 3000 1MB arrays and filling them with random data) the application happily continued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that we were using a library which was using `HttpClient` without disposing it, thereby leaking sockets.

We have been using this library for a while on Windows, but apparently the sockets are eventually closed by the finalizer, but not on Linux.

I finally ran the application on a regular Linux machine, making it easier to monitor the OS. It turns out that this command

```
$ lsof -p <PID>
```

returned thousands of lines like this

```
dotnet  15613 ec2-user  215u     sock                0,8      0t0  4968805 protocol: TCP
dotnet  15613 ec2-user  219u     sock                0,8      0t0  4968844 protocol: TCP
dotnet  15613 ec2-user  220u     sock                0,8      0t0  4968236 protocol: TCP
dotnet  15613 ec2-user  221u     sock                0,8      0t0  4968247 protocol: TCP
...
```

Converting the `HttpClient` usage to singleton solved the issue.